# How to make CSS 3 columns stay in their posisiton?

Tags: css

I have got a problem with my 3 columns layout (960.css).
This is the condition:

c-left,c-center,c-right

The query `ORDER BY id_post DESC LIMIT 6` inside center column to show article as many as 6 articles works, but when i use `LIMIT 12` it doesn't. columns-right will be in down side.

Any thoughts?

html:

```
    <div class="grid_4">
    <div class="populer_left">
        <div class="title_kiri">
            Berita Terpopuler
        </div>
        <div class="batas_tengah"></div>
        <div class="b_populer">
            <?php include 'beritapopuler.php';?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_7">
    <div class="populer_center">
        <div class="title_tengah">
            Berita Terbaru
        </div>
        <div class="batas_tengah"></div>
        <div class="isi_berita">
            <?php include 'loadar.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_5">
    <div class="populer_right">
        <div class="title_kanan">
            Opini
        </div>
        <div class="batas_tengah"></div>
        <div class="b_opini">
          <?php include 'beritaopini.php'; ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.populer_left { 
      float:left;
      width:220px;
      height:auto;
      clear:both;
      padding-bottom:15px;
      background:#29aa6b;
      border-radius:2px;
}

.populer_right {
      float:right;
      width:280px;
      height:auto;
      clear:both;
      padding-bottom:15px;
      background:#3f83ab;
      border-radius:2px;
}

.populer_center {
      float:left;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
      width:400px;
      height:auto;
      background:#0e62aa;
      border-radius:2px;
}
```

Comment: Is this responsive ? Also, using percentage instead of fix width might help

Comment: no, it's not....... i don't know what i have to do...

Comment: Need to see html as well. The question is not very clear

Comment: `.populer_center` is missing padding bottom. While left and right have padding bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display table`, and `table-cell` property.

Here: **Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/LUCNY/10/

```
#wrapper { border: 2px solid red;overflow:hidden; display: table; width:900px;}
.populer-left { 
  width: 220px; 
  display:table-cell;
  float:left; 
  padding-bottom:15px;
  background:#29aa6b;
  border-radius:2px;
}
.populer-center { 
  display:table-cell;
  width: 400px; 
  float:left; 
  background-color: green; 
  background:#0e62aa;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  border-radius:2px;
}
.populer-right {
  display:table-cell;
  width: 280px; 
  float:left; 
  padding-bottom:15px;
  background:#3f83ab;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

Comment: What does work ? Can you elaborate ? Which browser ?